# report builder exclude column from row total

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I have a matrix which works nicely. I want to add a row total but exclude data from one column within the column group.

So if my column group has columns for Development, Software, Data Quality and Valid, I want to total only the first three columns and not the "Valid" column.

How can i exclude a column from the total?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilise "reportitems" to calculate this total value, see attached example:
[image]